# How to get rows presented as null value which do not exists in joined table (oracle)?

Tags: oracle

I have to run report on my Oracle 11g database which whill show customers with their default shopping account number. Unfortunately for me I am struggling with it because of two reasons:

1) customers data and shopping account number are on separate tables:

- table customers (let's call it `T1`) has default customers data like `cust_id, cust_file_number, cust_name`
- table customers_parameters (let's call it `T2`) has data like `cupr_cust_id, cupr_code, cupr_value`

2) if a customers has set by himself default shopping account number then a row is inserted into `T2` with data:

- `cupr_cust_id: from T1.cust_id`
- `cupr_code: 'DFLT_SHOPP_ACC'`
- `cupr_value: cust. account number`

Otherwise, if customers did not set this account row DOES NOT exists on `T2`

My problem is how to get query result as presented on example below:

```
cust_id  cust_file_number    cust_name         cupr_code          cupr_value
1          3455656            cust1          DFLT_SHOPP_ACC        1234456
2          8621123            cust2          DFLT_SHOPP_ACC        455465789
3          56756234           cust3          DFLT_SHOPP_ACC        no_account
etc.
```

General idea is to present all the records here even if customers has no default account - then I'd like to have there a null value or 'no_account'. I've tried outer join, case statement and other magic but nothing seem to work.

Please help.

Comment: Please post your attempts and the problems they have; this way we could help you to edit them and fit your need

Comment: Where comes the 'FLT_SHOPP_ACC ' on cust3 from?

Comment: My bad, should be DFLT_SHOPP_ACC , I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is the outer join, as you tried and as Bob has shown.

I think I know where the problem is though.

Clearly Bob's solution is incomplete, because you must filter by `cupr_code = 'DFLT_SHOPP_ACC'`. So, I suspect in your initial tries (and perhaps if you tried to use Bob's solution), you added this as a `where` clause.

The problem is that if you add it at the very end, it will throw out the rows for customers without a default account (which the outer join included in its results).

The correct solution is to add the `where` clause to `T2` **before** you do the outer join, like so:

```
select t1.cust_id, t1.cust_file_number, t1.cust_name, t3.cupr_code, t3.cupr_value
from t1 left outer join (
                          select *
                          from   t2
                          where  cupr_code = 'DFLT_SHOPP_ACC'
         ) t3
         on t3.cupr_cust_id = t1.cust_id;
```

Now, I just noticed you want the string `DFLT_SHOPP_ACC` to appear in the `cupr_code` column even if the customer didn't have a default shopping account. Do you know how to do that or do you need help with it as well? (Hint: you can do this with an NVL, but there is a much simpler solution - just include it as a constant string and give it a name, all in the `select` clause.)

Better question though, since this report ONLY shows default accounts, why do you even need that column in the results? It is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you need to use an OUTER JOIN, which requires data be present in the first table but allows data to optionally be present in the second table. So your query should look something like

```
SELECT T1.cust_id,
       T1.cust_file_number,
       T1.cust_name,
       T2.cupr_code,
       T2.cupr_value
  FROM T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T2.cupr_cust_id = T1.CUST_ID
```

Best of luck.

Comment: This query shows only those customers who have their default shopping account number set - now comes the struggle: how to add here those customers without that account?